On the notation $ \vec F\cdot \mathrm ds $ for line integrals
Let $ \vec F\in \mathscr X(\mathbb R^3) $ be a vector field on the manifold $ \mathbb R^3 $ endowed with the Euclidean metric $ \mathrm ds^2 $.
The inner product $ \vec F\mathop{\lrcorner} \mathrm ds^2 $ of $ \vec F $ with the metric $ \mathrm ds^2 $ is a $ 1 $-form on $ \mathbb R^3 $: at a point $ p\in \mathbb R^3 $ it eats a tangent vector $ \vec v_p\in \mathrm T_p\mathbb R^3 $ and spits out the scalar $ \bigl(\vec F\mathop{\lrcorner} \mathrm ds^2\bigr)_p(\vec v_p) = \mathrm ds^2(\vec F(p),\vec v_p) = \vec F(p)\cdot \vec v_p $.
In elementary (physics) textbooks the line integral $ \int_\gamma \vec F\mathop{\lrcorner} \mathrm ds $ along some curve $ \gamma $ is denoted by $ \int_\gamma \vec F\cdot \mathrm d\vec s $, suggesting that $ \vec F\cdot \mathrm d\vec s $ is some formal symbol meant to denote the aforementioned $ 1 $-form $ \vec F\mathop{\lrcorner} \mathrm ds^2 $.
I find this slightly misleading. My questions are: Why the inner product? How is $ \mathrm d\vec s $ defined? Is it only a notational shortcut?

I have never seen the notation $\vec{F}\mathop\lrcorner\mathrm ds,.$ Can you give a reference? Assuming $\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dx\otimes \mathrm dx+\mathrm dy\otimes \mathrm dy+\mathrm dz\otimes \mathrm dz$ I'd say that $\vec{F}\mathop\lrcorner\mathrm ds^2$ is, in fancy notation, a more consistent way of writing the classic $\vec{F}\cdot \mathrm ds,.$ Whatever we do: we mean the one-form $F_x,dx+F_y,dy+F_z,dz,.$

@KurtG. That is pretty standard notation for the interior product; see for instance Sternberg’s Lectures on Differential Geometry or Loomis and Sternberg’s Advanced Calculus.

OP: you can think of it as the inner product between a vector-valued map and a vector-valued $1$-form.

@KurtG. what you say is definitely correct, i.e., $ \vec F\cdot \mathrm ds = \delta_{ii}F^i\mathrm dx^i $. But of course $ \mathrm ds $ is not the "vector" $ (\mathrm dx^1,\mathrm dx^2,\mathrm dx^3) $. The reason I asked this question is that it is not clear to me whether the inner product "dot" in $ \vec F\cdot \mathrm ds = \vec F\mathop{\lrcorner}\mathrm ds = i_{\vec F}\mathrm ds $ is only there as a mnemonic, or if it can be seen as a real inner product defined somewhere.

Be very careful here. $ds$ is not a $1$-form. The usual physicist's $\vec F\cdot d\vec s$ is different, as $d\vec s$ represents a vector-valued $1$-form. Contracting the symmetric $2$-tensor $ds^2$ with $\vec F$ is a different matter. Your writing $ds(\vec F,\vec v)$ really makes no sense. This should be the metric tensor $ds^2$ here. I don't at all agree with @peek-a-boo that this is standard notation.

@TedShifrin the non-standard notation are you referring to $\lrcorner$ for the interior product (plugging a vector field into a covariant slot of a tensor field)? because that is surely prevalent, though perhaps the $\iota$ notation is more common. But if you’re referring to the $ds$ vs $d\vec{s}$, then I must admit, I didn’t pay attention to that initially (nowadays I rarely use the arrow for vectors, so I didn’t even register it lol), and of course you’re right there.

I’m fine with contraction. As I said, it’s not $ds$ versus $d\vec s$ here. It’s that $ds$ (whatever that means) should be $ds^2$.

@TedShifrin you are right: my notation confused the metric $ \mathrm ds^2 $ with the "object" $ \mathrm d\vec s $. I edited the question, I hope it's more clear now. (Btw, I'm not used to putting arrows over vectors too, so I probably made a bit of mess previously)

Too long for a comment. I believe we have clarified the matter by agreeing in the comments that the correct notation should be
$$
F\mathop\lrcorner\,ds^2=\iota_F\,ds^2=F\cdot ds=F_x\,dx+F_y\,dy+F_z\,dz\,.
$$
(If you want you can put a $\vec{}$ over $F$ or $ds$ but not over $ds^2\,.$)
Here $ds^2$ is the metric tensor $dx\otimes dx+dy\otimes dy+dz\otimes dz$ whose innterior product with a vector field should be defined in the same way as it is usually done for $n$-forms [1] p. 447: write $F=F_x\,\partial_x+F_y\,\partial_y+F_z\,\partial_z$ and contract
$$
F\mathop\lrcorner\,ds^2=F_x\,\underbrace{dx(\partial_x)}_{1}\,dx\,+F_y\,\underbrace{dy(\partial_y)}_{1}\,dy+F_z\,\underbrace{dz(\partial_z)}_{1}\,dz\,.
$$
In $F\cdot ds$ the vector field $F$ should be interpreted as the tuple of its components and $ds$ as the vector valued one-form with "components" $dx,dy,dz\,.$
[1] L.H. Loomis, S. Sternberg, Advanced Calculus. Revised Edition 1990.
